# In function âvoid warning: extra `â` gets appended somehow

Tags: c++, makefile

Whenever I compile my C++ code using make, I always get warning as -

```
/client/main.cc: In function âvoid print_rows(cql::cql_result_t&)â:
/client/main.cc:41:5: warning: label âstdâ defined but not used [-Wunused-label]
```

Somehow I always see `â` appended in my print_rows method and std as well.. But whenever I go on vi editor, I never see  `â` appeneded..

Is there anything I am missing? How to fix this problem?

Comment: It's supposed to be a '

Comment: @chris, would that have something to do with the shell using a different character format?

Comment: I've seen this happen before on some systems. It's harmless